# Change the url dinamically to switch between apis key with an if statement

Tags: php, api, if-statement, curl, dynamic

Here's my problem:

I need to send some data from a CRM to another. Now the problem is that the URL has to be dynamic because unfortunately, it has different API keys.

So let's say that I want to send some data, based on the locations, it will change the API key. Better to make an example:

```
    $url = 'https://my_website/api/student/add';

    $myvars = 'firstName=' . $new_array['firstName'] 
                           . '&lastName=' . $new_array['lastName'] 
                           . '&locationID=' . $new_array['locationID'] 
                           . '&currentStatus=' . $new_array['currentStatus'];

    $apikey;
    function apikey() {
        if ($new_array['locationID'] == 1) {
            $apikey = $toronto;
        } elseif($new_array['locationID'] == 2) {
            $apikey = $newyork;
        } else {
           $apikey = $rome;
        }
    }

    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

First thing first: where should I add my $apikey to automatically add it to the end of my URL?

My fields come from another array:

```
$new_array = [
    'firstName' => $json_final['core']['firstname']['value'],
    'lastName' => $json_final['core']['lastname']['value'],
]; ..
```

And so on, you got the idea.

Every API keys, as I stated at the very beginning, are different:

```
$toronto = '123456';
$rome = '789101112';
```

and so on.

So essentially I need to build a dynamic URL based on the form that my user has already sent on my website and I want to direct it to two CRM. Ignoring the first one, which is already ok, I need to create the second URL to post the same data to the other with dynamic features.

Comment: `$myvars="&key=$apikey"` ?

Comment: to add it at the very end? I will try

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with building that URL?

Comment: I need to change it dynamically based on the location, which is actually only a number, something like that:

function apikey() {
 echo $new_array['locationID'];
 echo '<br>';
 if ($new_array['locationID'] == 1) {
  $apikey = $toronto;
 } elseif($new_array['locationID'] == 2) {
  $apikey = $newyork;
 } else {
  $apikey = 'unknown';
 }
 return $apikey;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a PHP function that does what you're doing here:

```
    $myvars = 'firstName=' . $new_array['firstName'] 
. '&lastName=' . $new_array['lastName'] 
. '&locationID=' . $new_array['locationID'] 
. '&currentStatus=' . $new_array['currentStatus'];
```

You can use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for this:

```
$myvars = http_build_query($new_array);
```

As far as that function:

```
function apikey() {
    if ($new_array['locationID'] == 1) {
        $apikey = $toronto;
    } elseif($new_array['locationID'] == 2) {
        $apikey = $newyork;
    } else {
       $apikey = $rome;
    }
}
```

It doesn't do anything. It doesn't return anything, and it does not address the `$apikey` defined outside the function [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

I would suggest creating an array that associates locationID with API key. I'd also suggest loading this from a config file so you won't have to change your code if an API key changes.

```
$keys = [
    1 => '123456',
    2 => '789101112',
    //etc.
];
```

Then you can use the locationID in `$new_array` to reference that. Add it to the array and then build the query.

```
$new_array['apiKey'] = $keys[$new_array['locationID']];
$myvars = http_build_query($new_array);
```

Comment: Almost, but the last part of the code: 
$new_array['apiKey'] = $keys[$new_array['locationID']];
$myvars = http_build_query($new_array); 
doesn't return the api key

Comment: Hmmm, have you put that code inside a function, by any chance? There are a couple of other things I'd like to mention if so.

Comment: what function? Should I use at the end just an equal sign or .=? I mean should I concatenate the last part?

Comment: I'm gonna post the new code soon, but your hint was very precious!

Comment: I will mark it for sure as soon as I finish to test it!

Answer (score 0):

something like this will do, if i understood it correct

```
function getApiKey($locationId) {
  $apiKeys = [
    1 => 12345, 2 => 6789... // key is the locationId and value is the api key
  ];
  return !empty($apiKeys[$locationId]) ? $apiKeys[$locationId] : $apiKeys['defaultKey'];
}

$myvars = 'firstName=' . $new_array['firstName'] 
. '&lastName=' . $new_array['lastName'] 
. '&locationID=' . $new_array['locationID'] 
. '&currentStatus=' . $new_array['currentStatus']
. '&apikey=' . getApiKey($new_array['locationID']);
```

Comment: function getApiKey($locationId) {
  $apiKeys = [
    1 => 12345, 2 => 6789... // key is the locationId and value is the api key
  ];
  return !empty($apiKeys[$locationId]) ? $apiKeys[$locationId] : $apiKeys['defaultKey'];
} ..

Where is defined the $locationID variable here? My variable is $new_array['locationID'] so if I try to return the argument of $locationID, will I get NULL??